# Removing seconds from time and rounding the minutes

Tags: php, laravel, datetime

I'm storing time entries to a variable called duration. So right now If I log a time entry, it will be in the standard format: ex) 12:30:00

What I want to do is remove the seconds part of the time entry and round the minutes to every 15th minute. Also I'de like to remove the 0 in the front of if the times before 10.

So 09:00:00 would become 9

09:30:00 would be come 9:30

So 12:30:00 would be 12:30.

12:08:00 would be 12:15

12:34:00 would be 12:30 ect ect.

Here's the code I was using:

```
    $duration = '';

    if ($seconds < 0) {
        $duration = '-';
        $seconds  = abs($seconds);
    }

    $hours    = floor($seconds / 3600);
    $seconds -= $hours * 3600;
    $minutes  = floor($seconds / 60);
    $seconds -= $minutes * 60;

    return $duration . sprintf('%d:%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
}
```

and here's a sample output:

```
1 => "12:20:00"
```

Comment: Can you provide the output which you are getting?

Comment: Use [DataTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [DateInterval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
 $currentTime = strtotime('12:34:00');
 echo 'Rounded Up 15 Minutes time: ' . date('H:i',round($currentTime / (15 * 60)) * (15 * 60));
//output - Rounded Up 15 Minutes time: 12:30
```

If this

```
 $currentTime = strtotime('12:08:00');
 echo 'Rounded Up 15 Minutes time: ' . date('H:i',round($currentTime / (15 * 60)) * (15 * 60));
//output - Rounded Up 15 Minutes time: 12:15
```

check demo.  [demo](https://3v4l.org/ukHgU)

For round, you may check with minutes zero condition like.

```
$currentTime = strtotime('9:00:00');
 if(date('i',ceil($currentTime / (15 * 60)) * (15 * 60)) == 00){
    echo date('H',ceil($currentTime / (15 * 60)) * (15 * 60));  
 }
```

Comment: I think the timezone is different. I used `date()` it'll take UTC default to make sure your time zone is UTC or different.

Comment: Yea it was a timezone issue, thank you. How would I modify this code to make it cut off a 0 if the time is before 10. I updated my OP with examples.

Comment: Please check carefully I used `ceil` in the demo but in the answer it's `round`. Let me change the demo link so you might check it @Jeto

Comment: Just checked. 11:44, rounds up to 11:45. Honestly that's fine with what i'm trying to do. I can edit the OP to make things more clear.

Comment: @DilipHirapara I found an issue with that code. I want it so I get the hours without any leading zeros, so 09:00, would be 9:00. For some reason when the values are before 10:00:00, so when the hours are single digit numbers, the time showed is 00:00. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I didn't get you.. Can you tell me what is your input and output and what your expected output??